# Spiral timeline with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

I want to make a spiral timeline like the  [image in *Nature* seen here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41559-017-0138) but I really do not know how to do it. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you don't already know how to do a chunk of this, I'd suggest drawing it in your favourite drawing programme and either exporting code for LaTeX or including the image as an external one with `\includegraphics`. If you do know how to do most of it, please post the code you've got. Obviously, somebody may take a fancy to it and do everything for you, but I always recommend including a duck to maximise your chances in that case. Admittedly, there is always the danger that you will get nothing but ducks in the answers if you do that.

Comment: You may want to attribute this image to https://www.nature.com/articles/s41559-017-0138/figures/1

Comment: Here is an MWE `\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[domain=0:13,smooth]plot(-\x r:\x*0.95)plot(-\x r:\x*1.05);
\end{document}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 Why `9` for the border?

Comment: Aren't there certain legal issues with asking and answering this question? Given the source @samcarter linked ....

Comment: @cfr `10` will take one more byte.

Comment: If you want to draw something on your own, a good starting point could be: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/rooty-helix/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/131901)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Be fair. The OP didn't post it as an answer. Rather, it is the question which you complain it fails to address.

Comment: @cfr The message is automatic (from review). It seems strange to me that I could have clicked on it if this was a question at that time.